# Ethereum Private test set up

Tags: testing

I am trying to set up my first test ethereum application. I started with the full ethereum get which took 10 hours to sync and found I needed Ether. I am trying to model an idea. I used

```
 geth --datadir Simons-MacBook-Pro:documents New Folder With Items init Simons-MacBook-Pro:documents private testnet.json --networkid 3156 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 console
```

to build a new testbed. But it is still going 30 minutes later. I am not sure what this command is doing and whether it is doing a full sync. I though my json file would limit the creation.